# HTML Input Breaking

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I'm simply moving around some HTML in my file and the input labels are breaking oddly. Everything else on the page works aside from the labels directly above the radio buttons (yet the labels work when the radio buttons are below other html elements).

```
<div class="col-sm-6 firstchild">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="templateName">Template Name
                <span class="text-danger">*</span>
            </label>
            <span class="help-tip">
                <p>Please confirm the Template Name</p>
            </span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="templateName" id="templateName" placeholder="Add Template Name"
             (keydown.Tab)="checkDuplicateTemplates($event)" (blur)="checkDuplicateTemplates($event)" />
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!form.controls['templateName'].valid && form.controls['templateName'].touched">You must enter Temaplte Name.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="language">Language</label>
            <span class="help-tip">
                <p>Confirm the Language</p>
            </span>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="language">
                <option value="english">English</option>
            </select>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['language'].hasError('required') && form.controls['language'].touched">You must enter Language.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Piece that was moved-->
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="approvalrequired">Will be used for External Client:</label>
        <span class="help-tip">
            <p>Select Yes or No</p>
        </span>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" id="externalClientYes" class="form-control" formControlName="approvalrequired" value="Y" />
                <label for="externalClientYes">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" id="externalClientNo" class="form-control" formControlName="approvalrequired" value="N" />
                <label for="externalClientNo">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--End of piece-->
    <div class="form-group emailSubject">
        <label class="control-label" for="emailSubject">Subject:</label>
        <span class="help-tip">
            <p>Subject of the email template</p>
        </span>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" formControlName="emailSubject" placeholder="Add Email Subject..." maxlength="400"></textarea>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['emailSubject'].hasError('required') && form.controls['emailSubject'].touched">You must enter the Email Subject</div>
    </div>
```

The same problem also occurs when I try to ad check boxes inputs beneath the two input labels as well. I am beyond stuck on why this is happening. I know it is solely the HTML too (I've reloaded a previous version of the HTML [before adding/moving any other input] and it works fine).

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

So I've narrowed down on the problem a bit more, but what the issue even is remains unclear.

So I took out my changes accordingly and made an empty form group underneath the problematic code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 firstchild">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="templateName">Template Name 
                    <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <span class="help-tip">
                    <p>Please confirm the Template Name</p>
                </span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="templateName" id="templateName" placeholder="Add Template Name"
                 (keydown.Tab)="checkDuplicateTemplates($event)" (blur)="checkDuplicateTemplates($event)" />
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!form.controls['templateName'].valid && form.controls['templateName'].touched">You must enter Temaplte Name.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="language">Language</label>
                <span class="help-tip">
                    <p>Confirm the Language</p>
                </span>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="language" id="language">
                    <option value="english">English</option>
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['language'].hasError('required') && form.controls['language'].touched">You must enter Language.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">

        </div>
    </div>
```

The inputs still work at this point. But if I put ANYTHING in the , then inputs break again. Does anyone have a clue why the inputs become what seems to be disabled (but they aren't, nor are they invalid).

Also this is not a project where I have control over how the CSS is used so I am not able to try any answers that require editing the CSS.

Comment: I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap margin or padding classes for each div in bootstrap 4. 
Like mb-1 for margin-bottom. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) for more

```
.mb-1 {
  margin-left: ($spacer * .25) !important;
}
```

Alternatively, use css for achieving same -

```
.mg-b {
      margin-bottom: 25px !important;
    }
```

Use this class in all your divs where breaking is happening.

*Also you should provide name attribute in your radio buttons to avoid both option being selected.

Answer (score 0):

The `label` tag's `for` attribute has to correspond to an `input` or `textarea`'s `id` attribute for it to work.

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 firstchild">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="templateName">Template Name 
                <span class="text-danger">*</span>
            </label>
            <span class="help-tip">
                <p>Please confirm the Template Name</p>
            </span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="templateName" id="templateName" placeholder="Add Template Name"
             (keydown.Tab)="checkDuplicateTemplates($event)" (blur)="checkDuplicateTemplates($event)" />
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!form.controls['templateName'].valid && form.controls['templateName'].touched">You must enter Temaplte Name.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="language">Language</label>
            <span class="help-tip">
                <p>Confirm the Language</p>
            </span>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="language" id="language">
                <option value="english">English</option>
            </select>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['language'].hasError('required') && form.controls['language'].touched">You must enter Language.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Piece that was moved-->
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="approvalrequired">Will be used for External Client:</label>
        <span class="help-tip">
            <p>Select Yes or No</p>
        </span>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" id="externalClientYes" class="form-control" formControlName="approvalrequired" value="Y" />
                <label for="externalClientYes">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" id="externalClientNo" class="form-control" formControlName="approvalrequired" value="N" />
                <label for="externalClientNo">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--End of piece-->
    <div class="form-group emailSubject">
        <label class="control-label" for="emailSubject">Subject:</label>
        <span class="help-tip">
            <p>Subject of the email template</p>
        </span>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" formControlName="emailSubject" placeholder="Add Email Subject..." maxlength="400" id="emailSubject"></textarea>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['emailSubject'].hasError('required') && form.controls['emailSubject'].touched">You must enter the Email Subject</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For some reason this works in the "run snippet" portion of stack overflow but not for my webpage... Do you have any clue why this might be?